# How can I align these entries, horizontally and vertically

Tags: align, multicolumn

Here is an example of code that demonstrates this problem.

```
$   \text{Let } $ A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ \text{Use the determinant and anjoint of }$ A$ \text{ to calcluate } $A^{-1}$ \text{.}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{align*}
        { C }_{ 1,1 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 1+1 }\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 6 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=-27 \\
        { C }_{ 2,1 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 2+1 }\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=-26\\
        { C }_{ 3,1 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 3+1 }\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=16 \\
        \end{align*}
        \begin{align*} 
        { C }_{ 1,2 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 1+2 }\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=-15\\
        { C }_{ 2,2 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 2+2 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=1\\
        { C }_{ 3,2 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 3+2 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=-22\\
        \end{align*}        
        \begin{align*}
        { C }_{ 1,3 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 1+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=7\\
        { C }_{ 2,3 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 2+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=-19\\
        { C }_{ 3,3 }&={ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ 3+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\\ &=1\\
        \end{align*}        
        \begin{align*}
        \end{align*}        
    \end{multicols}

$
```

Note: note sure why the code is not rendering.

In any case here is [link](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58ab5edac66775264820d398) to the example, where it renders and you can see what is going on. It appears there is a slight slant on the expressions, I want to make it look square. So that is why I am thinking about horizontal and vertical alignment.

Please comment with any questions or if something is not clear.

Comment: Welcome  to TeX.SE. By `not rendering` you do mean the display of LaTeX output here? Well, that's not done here on TeX.SE. But please complete your document to make it compilable and please do not post such fragments only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `multicol` package and its `multicols` environment, I'd like to suggest you use three side-by-side `minipage` environments, each with width `0.3\textwidth` and separated by `\hfill` (to maximize the horizontal separation).

Note that, in your original code, the presence of `\\` after the second `\begin{align*}` directive is almost surely not correct. Furthermore, all nine instances of `{ \left( -1 \right)  }` may be written more simply as `(-1)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. 
Use the determinant and adjoint of $A$ to calcluate~$A^{-1}$.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.333\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
C_{ 1,1 }&=(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix} 1 &  6 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=-27 \\
C_{ 2,1 }&=(-1)^{2+1}\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=-26\\
C_{ 3,1 }&=(-1)^{3+1}\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=16
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*} 
C_{ 1,2 }&=(-1)^{1+2}\begin{vmatrix} 1 &  6 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=-15\\
C_{ 2,2 }&=(-1)^{2+2}\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=1\\
C_{ 3,2 }&=(-1)^{3+2}\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\  1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=-22
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}     
\begin{align*}
C_{ 1,3 }&=(-1)^{ 1+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=7\\
C_{ 2,3 }&=(-1)^{ 2+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=-19\\
C_{ 3,3 }&=(-1)^{ 3+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\  1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
         &=1
\end{align*}        
\end{minipage}     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Found an error in my code. $$ C_{2,3} $$ should be negative.

Comment: @user1787331 - Thanks; I've fixed the sign of the `C_{2,3}` term.

Answer (score 4):

You can exploit the fact that the indices are one digit long, so they have the same width.

A single `alignat` with a suitable definition for printing cofactors also allows for easy input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cofactor}[4]{%
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  C_{#1,#2}&=(-1)^{#1+#2}
  \begin{vmatrix}#3\end{vmatrix}\\
  &=#4
  \end{aligned}
}

\begin{document}

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. 
Use the determinant and adjoint of $A$ to calculate $A^{-1}$.
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\cofactor{1}{1}{1 & 6 \\ 5 & 3}{-27}
&\quad
&\cofactor{1}{2}{1 & 6 \\ -2 & 3}{-15}
&\quad
&\cofactor{1}{3}{1 & 1 \\ -2 & 5}{7}
\\
&\cofactor{2}{1}{2 & -4 \\ 5 & 3}{-26}
&\quad
&\cofactor{2}{2}{3 & -4 \\ -2 & 3}{1}
&\quad
&\cofactor{2}{3}{3 & 2 \\ -2 & 5}{-19}
\\
&\cofactor{3}{1}{2 & -4 \\ 1 & 6}{16}
&\quad
&\cofactor{3}{2}{3 & -4 \\ 1 & 6}{-22}
&\quad
&\cofactor{3}{3}{3 & 2 \\ 1 & 1}{1}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the text before the alignment can be typed in much more directly.

[image]

This might be a case for `flalign` (full length align):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cofactor}[4]{%
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  C_{#1,#2}&=(-1)^{#1+#2}
  \begin{vmatrix}#3\end{vmatrix}\\
  &=#4
  \end{aligned}
}

\begin{document}

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. 
Use the determinant and adjoint of $A$ to calculate $A^{-1}$.
\begin{flalign*}
&\cofactor{1}{1}{1 & 6 \\ 5 & 3}{-27}
&
&\cofactor{1}{2}{1 & 6 \\ -2 & 3}{-15}
&
&\cofactor{1}{3}{1 & 1 \\ -2 & 5}{7}
\\
&\cofactor{2}{1}{2 & -4 \\ 5 & 3}{-26}
&
&\cofactor{2}{2}{3 & -4 \\ -2 & 3}{1}
&
&\cofactor{2}{3}{3 & 2 \\ -2 & 5}{-19}
\\
&\cofactor{3}{1}{2 & -4 \\ 1 & 6}{16}
&
&\cofactor{3}{2}{3 & -4 \\ 1 & 6}{-22}
&
&\cofactor{3}{3}{3 & 2 \\ 1 & 1}{1}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Three simple `aligned` environments with `\hfill` in between will span the whole line in a clear and readable way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 1 & 6 \\ -2 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. 
Use the determinant and adjoint of $A$ to calcluate~$A^{-1}$.

\medskip\noindent%
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    C_{ 1,1 }&=(-1)^{1+1}\begin{vmatrix} 1 &  6 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=-27 \\
    C_{ 2,1 }&=(-1)^{2+1}\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 5 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=-26\\
    C_{ 3,1 }&=(-1)^{3+1}\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ 1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=16
\end{aligned}\hfill
\begin{aligned}[t]
    C_{ 1,2 }&=(-1)^{1+2}\begin{vmatrix} 1 &  6 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=-15\\
    C_{ 2,2 }&=(-1)^{2+2}\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ -2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=1\\
    C_{ 3,2 }&=(-1)^{3+2}\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -4 \\  1 & 6 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=-22
\end{aligned}\hfill
\begin{aligned}[t]
    C_{ 1,3 }&=(-1)^{ 1+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=7\\
    C_{ 2,3 }&=(-1)^{ 2+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\ -2 & 5 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=19\\
    C_{ 3,3 }&=(-1)^{ 3+3 }\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 2 \\  1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\\ 
             &=1
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Note: C23 should be negative. That was a mistake from my original post.